# Is the test condition computed each time through a loop in Python?

Tags: python, compiler-construction

```
# returns sum of individual digits in n (incorrect implementation)
def digit_sum(n):
  running_sum = 0
  count = 0
  while count < len(str(n)):
    rightmost = n % 10         # value of right-most digit
    running_sum += rightmost
    n = n // 10                # strip right-most digit
    count += 1
  return running_sum
```

Is the value of `len(str(n))` computed every time the condition is checked through each iteration of the `while` loop, or is `len(str(n))` evaluated the first time and stored some place to optimize execution?

In contrast to the following loop:

```
# returns sum of individual digits in n (correct implementation)
def digit_sum(n):
  running_sum = 0
  for _ in xrange(len(str(n))):
    rightmost = n % 10         # value of right-most digit
    running_sum += rightmost
    n = n // 10                # strip right-most digit
  return running_sum
```

Comment: This should be straightforward to test. I would certainly hope it is evaluated every time, otherwise a lot of loops couldn't be written correctly.

Comment: Why are you creating a `range` every time?

Comment: Yes, it is evaluated everytime in CPython. But why are you comparing an integer with `range()`?(It is always going to be True in Python2.)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: data flow analysis could establish that certain parts of the condition are not affected by the loop body. (Leaving aside pointer aliasing and concurrency issues.)

Answer (score 3):

It's computed every time. Python doesn't know that `str(n)` will always return the same thing every time. At compile time, for all it knows, this function might be called with an instance of

```
class IAmABadPersonWhoWantsPeopleToHaveABadTime(int):
    def __str__(self):
        if random.random() < 0.1:
            raise SyntaxError
        return super(IAmABadPersonWhoWantsPeopleToHaveABadTime, self).__str__()
```

and the program's correctness might rely on that 10% chance of a SyntaxError.

Also, don't compare numbers to `range` return values. That's definitely not doing what you want. A `for` loop is closer to what you wanted:

```
for _ in xrange(len(str(n))):
```

though it'd be simpler to use a `while`:

```
while n:
```

which keeps going as long as `n != 0`.